# Select only a row if one of the joined columns meets both conditions in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, outer-join

Please suppose these two tables:

users table:

| id | account_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

user_labels table:

| id | user_id | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | label1 |
| 2 | 2 | label2 |
| 3 | 1 | label1 |
| 4 | 1 | label2 |

now I want to select users who have both label1 and label2 columns, the users which has only one of these should not be returned in the result. for example, users 3 and 4 have only one of the labels then they should not appear in the result.

Please take a look at the following query, It will not work correctly because logically title column cannot be both 'label1' and 'label2'.

```sql
select u.id, STRING_AGG(l.title, ', ') AS titles from users u 
left outer join user_labels l on l.user_id = u.id 
where l.title = 'label1' AND l.title = 'label2';
```

how can I achieve this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Clearly your error(s) & goal will be faqs. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a group by with `string_agg`. Add the group by, then add a `having` clause:

```
select u.id, string_agg(l.title, ', ') as titles
from users u 
join user_labels l on u.id = l.user_id
where l.title in ('label1', 'label2')
group by u.id
having count(distinct l.title) = 2
```

Comment: For the *specific* case of `having count(distinct... >= 2` it's slightly more efficient, if obscure, to do `having min(l.title) <> max(l.title)`. Also if `l.title` is unique (as it should be) then you can just do `having count(*) = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query,

```
select id, titles from
(select u.id, STRING_AGG(l.title, ', ') AS titles,
count() over(partition by l.title) as cnt
 from users u 
left outer join user_labels l on l.user_id = u.id) T1
where cnt=2;
```